# Hibernate Envers: AuditQuery for selecting entity valid at given point in time

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I use Hibernate Envers with ValidityAuditStrategy. I want to select the version of an entity as it existed at a given point in time.

My revision info looks like this in SQL:

```
create table revinfo (
    rev int,
    revtstmp datetime2,
    primary key(rev)
);
```

My audited entities look like this:

```
create table products_aud (
    id long,
    name varchar(255),
    rev int,           -- this is a foreign key into revinfo
    revend int,        -- this is a foreign key into revinfo
    revtype smallint,
    primary key(id, rev)
);
```

For example, the user wants to see the version of a given entity, valid at 2019-03-05 16:00:00.

The SQL would have to look like this:

```
select * from (
select id, name, revtype, x.rev, revend, revtstmp
    from products_aud x join revinfo y
    on x.rev = y.rev
    where id = 14 and y.revtstmp <= '2019-03-05 16:00:00'
) as a
join (
select id, name, revtype, x.rev, revend, revtstmp
    from products_aud x left outer join revinfo y
    on x.revend = y.rev
    where id = 14 and (y.revtstmp >= '2019-03-05 16:00:00' or x.revend is null)
) as b
on a.rev = b.rev;
```

What does the AuditQuery have to look like? I am confused about the otherAlias parameter for `AuditProperty::leProperty(otherAlias, otherPropertyName)`.

So far I got this:

```
AuditQuery auditQuery = queryCreator.forRevisionsOfEntity(Product.class, true, true);
auditQuery.add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("revtstmp").leProperty(???, ???))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditReader.html#getRevisionNumberForDate-java.util.Date-

`AuditReader.getRevisionNumberForDate(java.util.Date date)`